# Solution to Laplace equation on a semi-infinite strip

Tags: boundary-value-problem, laplacian

$\Delta u=0$ where $x>0,y\in[0,1]$

$u$ is periodic in $y$, i.e.,
$u(x,0)=u(x,1)$

$u$ is constant at $x=0$, i.e., $u(0,y)=1$

$u$ stays bound at infinity i.e., $u(+\infty,y)=0$

Does there exist any solution that satisfies all the above boundary conditions?
I tried separation of variable and Fourier series which don't seem to work.

Comment: Have you applied the Laplace Transform on the $x$ variable?

Comment: I let $F(s,y)$ to be the Laplace transform of $u$ in $x$. Then I get an equation for $s^2F-s+F_{yy}=0$. The solution looks like $F=1/s+a(s)\cos(s y)+b(s)\sin(s y)$. Then I got stuck.

Comment: Apply the boundary conditions at $y=0$ and $y=1$ to get $F(s,y)=A(s)\cos(s(y-1/2))$.  Then, $u(x,y)=\mathscr{L}^{-1}(F(s,y))$.  Then, apply $u(0,y)=1$ to find $A(s)$.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm trying. But I think the last step can not be satisfied easily since $s$ and $y$ are entangled in $\cos(s(y-1/2))$